# flask search pagination is not working for next page

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Problem description: I have a list of players names stored in Sqlite db at the players table.
There is a search button [image: PlayerHome]. Now when I search a particular player `Nick` I get real count of players present in DB in this case `971`. My per page display is `10` [image: NickShow Result]. In this pagination the page nr `1` is ok, but as soon as I click page `2` it shows me the below error

How can I solve this?

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'text'
```

[image: ErrorMessage]

This is my `base.html` for `search`

```
  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search" method="POST">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" type="text" name="text">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

This is `app.py` for the `search` endpoint

```
    @app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.conn = sqlite3.connect(database)
    g.conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    g.cur = g.conn.cursor()


@app.teardown_request
def teardown(error):
    if hasattr(g, "conn"):
        g.conn.close()
    @app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @print_exceptions
    def search():
        """The function is used to test multi values url."""
        sql = "select count(*) from player_details where player like (?);"
        # this is where giving me the problem
        args = request.form['text']
        # each page is moving as if it's end point for search
        g.cur.execute(sql, [args])
        total = g.cur.fetchone()[0]
        print(total)
        page, per_page, offset = get_page_args()
        sql = "select id, player, floor from player_details where player like (?) limit {}, {}"
        print(sql.format(offset, per_page))
        g.cur.execute(sql.format(offset, per_page), [args])
        users = g.cur.fetchall()
        pagination = get_pagination(
            page=page,
            per_page=per_page,
            total=total,
            record_name="users",
        )
        return render_template(
            "index.html",
            users=users,
            page=page,
            per_page=per_page,
            pagination=pagination,
        )
    
    
    def get_css_framework():
        return current_app.config.get("CSS_FRAMEWORK", "bootstrap4")
    
    
    def get_link_size():
        return current_app.config.get("LINK_SIZE", "sm")
    
    
    def get_alignment():
        return current_app.config.get("LINK_ALIGNMENT", "")
    
    
    def show_single_page_or_not():
        return current_app.config.get("SHOW_SINGLE_PAGE", False)
    
    
    def get_pagination(**kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("record_name", "records")
        return Pagination(
            css_framework=get_css_framework(),
            link_size=get_link_size(),
            alignment=get_alignment(),
            show_single_page=show_single_page_or_not(),
            **kwargs
        )
```

************UPDATE************

I have made change to `search` functionality like below:

```
@app.route("/search/<name>/")
@app.route("/search/<name>")
@print_exceptions
def search(name):
    """The function is used to test multi values url."""
    sql = "select count(*) from player_details where player like (?);"
    args = ("%{}%".format(name),)
    print(args)
    # args = request.form.get("name")
    # if not args:
    #     args = request.form['text']
    # else:
    #     args = args

    g.cur.execute(sql, args)
    .....
    ....
```

Now it is working as API call in gui.. like this `http://localhost:5050/search/Alex` and then pagination from there on it's going smoothly.
[image: AlexSearchAPI]
But now the button search is not working... Is there any way I can add both button and API call together?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you click '2' the `text` field that used to hold Nick in the HTML has no value so the code `args = request.form['text']` crash with KeyError.
You need to populate the text field with Nick each time the page is rendered in the backend. This is user friendly as well since the user is able to see on what is the current search term

Comment: thanks as you suggested, I made the change, now it is working as an API call but not from the button. do you have any suggestions on how to combine both feature? I have updated my question?